# How to access a method/field of a constructor from a nested function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to access a field of a constructor from a nested function.

Here is my code:

```
var Box = function() {
  this.div = $("div#mydiv");
  this.guide = {
     div: $("div#mydiv2"),
     scroll: function() {
        $(document).scrollTo(this.div); //Want to scroll to mydiv2
        alert(Box.div.attr("id")); //Want to alert mydiv id
                                   //How do I access the div field of the Box constructor?
     }
  }
}
```

if I call the scroll method like this:

```
var a = new Box();

$("#button").click(function() {
a.guide.scroll();
});
```

`Box.div` is returning as undefined.

If I try to `alert` the `id` of the div property inside the `scroll` method as `this.div` it will use the div property inside the `guide` object. I've tried referencing the div field outside the `guide` object by using `Box.div` but this does not work. Please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the first row of the Box function:

```
var Box = function() {
    var self = this;
```

Then in the alert, use `self` instead of `this` as `this` is not referring to the top level function (box).

```
$(document).scrollTo(self.div);
```

Comment: @Topener--so does `self` always refer to the top level function?

Comment: @codeninja yes, because you defined `self` there, it does refer to that `this`

Comment: @Topener--Thank you. The answer seems obvious after you learn it haha!

Answer (score 2):

It's because the "this" objects in your scroll function refers to the function itself. You need to cache a reference to the outermost "this" object and use it instead. See this fiddle for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/tuando/kBc5K/